# Where might the given name Xelefon originate?

Tags: historical-linguistics, orthography, written-language, history, names

I was recently reading some historical records wherein a lady was mentioned, Olga Malar (née Cuch), born in "Napodiwka," Poland, in 1922. She was said to be the daughter of **Xelefon** Cuch and Jewdokia Romaniuk.

Every individual name on the record can be cross-referenced elsewhere, apart from the birthplace, and father's given name (**Xelefon**). Both are possibly misspellings, but of what?

Online, there are barely any concrete results for a search of *Xelefon*, or even possible permutations like *Kselefon*, *Helefon* or *Chelefon*.

It seems particularly unusual for the letter *x* to appear in Polish. It is not part of the standard alphabet, though it may appear in calques. However, even then, *x* is often substituted for *ks*, for example.

EDIT: No official answers by 2020.

Comment: "Xelefon" may be a misspelling of the more common name "Xenofon". "Napodiwka" may be a mistake for "na Podiwka" or "na Podwika", or "Napodwika". And of course, Poland in 1922 included a lot of territory in what is now Belarus, Ukraine, and Lithuania.

Comment: Thanks for that, "Ksenofon" is present in Polish via Greek. "Xelefon" is of course a terrible misspelling of "Xenofon" if it is such, but I wouldn't put it past some people.

Comment: Maybe, this is related to the telephone, a new technology at the time?

Comment: _-iwka_ certainly suggests a Belarussian or Ukrainian name; in Polish you would expect _-ówka_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google suggests a possible Turkish origin. Otherwise, the name may be a variant of Xenofon/Ksenofon, suggesting a Greek connection.

Comment: Can you be more explicit on "Google suggests a possible Turkish origin"?

Comment: No. But I’m happy to change the accepted answer if you can. @jk-ReinstateMonica